# How can the reach of natural attacks be increased?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, natural-weapon, reach

Is there a way to increase a creature's reach with all the creature's natural weapons so that the creature can make attacks of opportunity over a bigger area? I am aware of the feats [Lunge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/lunge-combat-final/), [Monkey Lunge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/monkey-lunge-combat/), and [Combat Patrol](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/combat-patrol-combat/) and the [*longarm bracers*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/longarm-bracers/), but those only seem to affect arm-based attacks, which isn't what I'm after.

My plan is to be a tank who can't just be ignored. I want to take fighter levels and the feat [Stand Still](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/stand-still-combat-final/) to keep foes from moving through my threatened area and getting to my allies. I'm sticking to natural attacks for roleplaying reasons.

Also, the game is a mythic game so that material can be included. Third-party material is acceptable, too, but, please, label it as such.

Comment: This kinda seems like a question that requires a list answer.

Comment: @GreedyRadish [Questions asking for a list are fine as long as the list is reasonable and the items asked for narrowly focused.](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/6442/8610) The number of ways to do what the asker wants seems small enough to me that I think it's fine, but if you can imagine a dozen screenfuls of ways to do this, then offering suggestions for narrowing the question further is totally valid.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Yes that is correct, thank you. I forget that Range generally refers to criticals.

Comment: @GreedyRadish I agree to a degree this is asking for a list but as Hey I Can Chan points out if the question is detailed enough it's not any issue. There are many questions on this site asking for similar things, some of them highly upvoted. This is a highly focused question with very few ways to accomplish it, otherwise, I wouldn't need to ask in the first place cause I can't find any more ways than what I listed already.

Answer (score 2):

Everything that increases your size to large would do that and the [aberrant](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advancedClassGuide/classes/bloodrager.html#aberrant) bloodline bloodrager specifically increases reach while raging from level 4 on.

Then there are some spells like [fluid form](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advancedPlayersGuide/spells/fluidForm.html#fluid-form) that increase your reach. [Long arm](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advancedClassGuide/spells/longArm.html#) is just for the arms which you do not seem to look for, while it would still help you to control the battlefield.

For self enlarging the [growth subdomain](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advancedPlayersGuide/coreClasses/cleric.html#growth-subdomain) would be an option but it only lasts 1 round per use.

I don't think this list is exhaustive but I hope it helps.

Comment: Regarding the Growth subdomain, after much experience I've learned that lasting 1 round per use is a feature not a bug.  Each Growth and Shrinkage gives you a tactically useful virtual 5' step.  This subdomain allows one to walk around normal-sized and swiftly grow large when needed.  For those times when you want to remain Large for a while there's a Potion of Enlarge Person (a discount at 50 gp) and the Domain Spell Enlarge Person (clunkier than a potion because it's a Full Round Action spell).  So this domain is actually the BEST and most flexible way to be large in Pathfinder.